Landscape SaaS account creation
how can I create a Landscape SaaS account? I have purchased Ubuntu Pro license, have a Ubuntu One account but do not see my purchased license. To my request to customersuccess@canonical.com I got no response but the documentation says:
"Landscape is available through a software-as-a-service (SaaS) model, hosted and managed by Canonical. Please contact customersuccess@canonical.com to request a Landscape SaaS account."
What can I do to get my Landscape SaaS account running?
Thanks!

That is a question for the Landscape guys. This is not the place where anyone here can answer it. Sorry. In your question you already gave the answer. Contact Canonical.
